# operand type clash: int is incompatible with utblProgramAllotment[user defined table type]

Tags: c#, sql

My C# code:

```
var Message = new SqlParameter("Message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000);

Message.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

var UserId = new SqlParameter("UserId ", SqlDbType.BigInt);
UserId.Value = Convert.ToInt64(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserIDKey"]);

var utblProgramAllotment = new SqlParameter("utblProgramAllotment", SqlDbType.Structured);
utblProgramAllotment.Value = dtProgrammeAllotments;
utblProgramAllotment.TypeName = "dbo.utblProgramAllotment";

try
{
    db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
         "exec uspInsertUpdateProgrammeAllotment    @UserId , @utblProgramAllotment, @Message OUTPUT",
         UserId, utblProgramAllotment, Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    vm.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
    Errorlog.WriteErrorlog(ex, "Programme Allotment", "");
```

and my procedure accepts:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE   [dbo].[uspInsertUpdateProgrammeAllotment] 
(      
    @utblProgramAllotment AS utblProgramAllotment READONLY,
    @UserId Bigint,
   @Message VARCHAR(8000) OUTPUT    
)
```

And the user defined table type is

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[utblProgramAllotment] AS TABLE(
    [ProgrammeScheduleIDKey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ProposalDetailsIDKey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SanctionOrderIDKey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ProgrammeIDKey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeIDKey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DistrictIDKey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TargetGroupIDKey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ProgrammeTitleIDKey] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [ProgramMode] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [ProgrammeDescription] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleStartDateDt] [datetime] NULL,
    [ApprovalDt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleEndDateDt] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProgrammeVenue] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [NoofParticipants] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Remarks] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [AccountsRemarks] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [ExamDateDt] [datetime] NULL,
    [ProgrammeTitle] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [DeletedFlg] [bit] NOT NULL
)
```

I am sending a data table to a sql stored procedure.
When I try to pass this data table from my c# it shows an exception as 
**operand type clash: int is incompatible with utblProgramAllotment this is user defined table type**

Comment: Please make an effort to format your post more cleanly. Fix the indentation, and make sure that non-code isn't treated as code.

Comment: This looks like a SQL Server generated error message. I think the key to solving this will be in the stored procedure itself. Could you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to pass a request to execute a stored procedure across as ad-hoc text rather than specifically as a stored procedure execution, then the parameter order should match:

```
exec uspInsertUpdateProgrammeAllotment @utblProgramAllotment, @UserId ,
                   @Message OUTPUT
```

Or you should name the parameters:

```
exec uspInsertUpdateProgrammeAllotment @UserId = @UserId ,
                   @utblProgramAllotment = @utblProgramAllotment,
                   @Message = @Message OUTPUT
```

See [`EXECUTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188332.aspx):

> When used with the `@parameter_name=value form`, parameter names and constants do not have to be supplied in the order in which they are defined in the module. However, if the `@parameter_name=value` form is used for any parameter, it must be used for all subsequent parameters.

and,

> If parameter names are not specified, parameter values must be supplied in the order defined in the module.